# MySQL ignores my index on a timestamp column

Tags: mysql, database, performance

My table has more than 800,000 rows. I need to improve the performance of a query which extract rows on a time interval.

My table:

```
CREATE TABLE `bets` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  ...
  `stamp_end` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `bets_stamp_end_index` (`stamp_end`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=875534 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Sometimes the index is used with this query:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM bets WHERE
bets.stamp_end BETWEEN '2016-05-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-06-01 00:00:00';

+----+-------------+-------+-------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys        | key                  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | bets  | **range** | bets_stamp_end_index | bets_stamp_end_index | 5       | NULL | **158210** | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
```

When I write this query, the index is never used:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM bets WHERE
stamp_end >= DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 56 DAY);

+----+-------------+-------+------+----------------------+------+---------+------+--------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys        | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+----------------------+------+---------+------+--------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | bets  | **ALL**  | bets_stamp_end_index | NULL | NULL    | NULL | **857651** | Using where; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------+------+----------------------+------+---------+------+--------+-----------------------------+
```

Note:
I already run OPTIMIZE TABLE. The first query use the index only for some date intervals.

Why the index is not used? Any solution?

Comment: Try `stamp_end >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 56 DAY`

Comment: Just tried: same problem with full table scan without using the index

Comment: Try `SELECT * FROM bets FORCE INDEX (bets_stamp_end_index) WHERE
stamp_end >=  CURDATE() - INTERVAL 56 DAY`

Comment: what database are you using, mysql or sql-server?

Comment: @RichBenner: That is MySQL.

Comment: BTW why use a `timestamp`? A `datetime` would be more appropriate.

Comment: @juergend it wouldn't be more appropriate because you'd have to store the time zone with each date somehow, and with a timestamp you know that it's UTC, it simply makes handling dates extremely easy - both on server and client side. The reason MySQL won't use an index is because index won't help reduce I/O. Forcing it won't make things faster, they will be slower. How many rows does the query return?

Comment: 800,000 records. The index makes is faster if used. And you don't have to store timezone in MySQL. Where did you get that?

Comment: @juergend If the table has 800 000 records and if the query returns 800 000 records then the index doesn't make it faster, it makes it **slower** because MySQL has to traverse the index first for no gain. If you receive a date from user using a web app and the user is in America, another one is in Europe and third is in Japan - how does the Indian guy know when was the record made relative to his time zone? That's why you have to store the time zone so you can pour the time from one cup to another to make the relative time accurate towards the one requesting the information.

Comment: Also, where did you get that you **don't** have to store the time zone for accurate time representation across the globe? It's just downright wrong NOT to save it. Timestamp alleviates this problem by eliminating the time zone and coerces everything to UTC (server's time zone plays the role in conversion though). It's common practice to use timestamp and not worry about potential timezone issues.

Comment: @juergend "FORCE INDEX (bets_stamp_end_index)" seems to work. Now it scans 160.000 rows, but the result set is only 24.000 rows.
What does this mean? The granularity of the index is too big? Can it be changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an index means bouncing back and forth between the index BTree and the data BTree.

If less than about 20% of the table needs to be accessed, the bouncing is worth it.

If more than that needs to be accessed, it is actually faster to scan the table, filtering out what the `WHERE` clause says to exclude.

(The 20% is imprecise, and the Optimizer does not always make the 'right' cutoff.)

Answer (score -1):

**SAMPLE**

```
MariaDB [bb]> CREATE TABLE `bets` (
    ->   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->   `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    ->
    ->   `stamp_end` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    ->   KEY `bets_stamp_end_index` (`stamp_end`)
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=875534 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.13 sec)

MariaDB [bb]>
MariaDB [bb]> INSERT INTO bets (stamp_end)
    -> SELECT DATE(now()) - INTERVAL seq HOUR  FROM seq_1_to_300000;
Query OK, 300000 rows affected, 1 warning (3.27 sec)
Records: 300000  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 1

MariaDB [bb]>
MariaDB [bb]> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM bets WHERE
    -> bets.stamp_end BETWEEN '2016-05-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-06-01 00:00:00';
+------+-------------+-------+-------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+------+------+-----------------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys        | key                  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                 |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+------+------+-----------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | bets  | range | bets_stamp_end_index | bets_stamp_end_index | 5       | NULL |  432 | Using index condition |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+------+------+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)

MariaDB [bb]>
MariaDB [bb]> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM bets WHERE
    -> stamp_end >= DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 56 DAY);
+------+-------------+-------+-------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+------+------+-----------------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys        | key                  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                 |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+------+------+-----------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | bets  | range | bets_stamp_end_index | bets_stamp_end_index | 5       | NULL | 1343 | Using index condition |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+------+------+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [bb]>
```

Comment: OP does not use `function(field)`. OP uses `field <= function(static_value)`