# MYSQL : How can we optimize the select query to fetch more than 1 million data using date range

Tags: mysql, database, performance

I have a table containing more than 1 million data and I am trying to fetch using a date range. I have indexed the date column and still its searching the entire rows. Can someone give a best solution to fix this up.

```
/** Table Structure **/

CREATE TABLE `claim_history` (
`claim_history_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`consultation_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`member_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`card_number` char(18) DEFAULT NULL,
`member_name` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
`network_code` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`mobile_number` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`soap_number` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`diagnosis_id` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`diagnosis_code` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`diagnosis_description` text,
`activity_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`activity_code` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`activity_description` text,
`activity_comments` text,
`activity_quantity` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`is_erx` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`lab_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`lab_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`session_no` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`net_amount` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`copay_pct` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`copay_amt` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`total_cost` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`is_edited` tinyint(1) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
`edit_comments` text,
`is_assigned_mcc` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0' 
`mcc_user` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`mcc_user_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`rule_name` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
`mcu_assigned_time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`mcu_action_performed_time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`mcu_open_time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`is_reappealed` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`reappeal_count` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
`denial_code` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`denial_description` text,
`rejection_comments` text,
`justification_comment` text,
`justification_reply` text,
`justification_count` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`edit_comment_reply` text,
`is_referral` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`is_physiotherapy` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`facility_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`provider_code` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`provider_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`doctor_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`doctor_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`referral_doctor_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`referral_clinic_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`pic_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`pic_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`ig_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`ig_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`is_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `history_created_on` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`history_last_modified_on` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00  00:00:00',
`created_on` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`created_by` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`last_modified_on` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`last_modified_by` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`claim_history_id`),
KEY `idx_consultation_id` (`consultation_id`),
KEY `idx_card_number` (`member_id`,`card_number`),
KEY `idx_provider` (`facility_id`),
KEY `idx_soap_number` (`soap_number`),
KEY `idx_created_on` (`created_on`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

/** SQL QUERY **/

```
SELECT fields FROM claim_history
    WHERE created_on BETWEEN '2017-01-01 00:00:00'
                         AND '2017-05-01 00:00:00';
```

Comment: Please show your table and query

Comment: An index won't help you with dates.  You have to scan every one.  if you had individual values like year, month, day, quarter, week, etc an index would help.  The problem is the date.

Comment: @duffymo - False.  `DATE`, `DATETIME`, and `TIMESTAMP` are perfectly good for doing range queries on.

Comment: What percentage of the rows are in that 4 months + one second time range?

Answer (score 0):

The query you provided has a syntax error.

Dependent on the range you put into your query, the query optimiser might use the index or not.
Try a really short range like one day and then use one year, you'll probably already see the difference.

Check this thread for more details:
[MySQL ignores my index on a timestamp column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37321296/mysql-ignores-my-index-on-a-timestamp-column)